# broadcasting vector multiplication with a 3 vector and n vector in julia

Tags: vector, julia, linear-algebra

I have a 3-vector `c = [0.7, 0.5, 0.2]` and I want to multiply it with everything in an n-vector `x = rand((-1,1),n)` such that I get a resulting n+2-vector y where `y[i] == x[i]*c[3] + x[i-1]*c[2] + x[i-2]*c[1]`

How should I do this in julia? I feel like there should be a way to broadcast the smaller 3 vector to all the values in the n vector. And for the edge cases, if i-1 or i-2 is out of bounds I just want zero for those components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want a convolution, with a twist that in a standard convolution the vector `c` would be reversed. You can use e.g. DSP.jl for this.

Is this what you want?

```
julia> using DSP

julia> c = [0.7, 0.5, 0.2]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.7
 0.5
 0.2

julia> conv([10, 100, 1000, 10000], reverse(c))
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
    1.9999999999996967
   25.0
  257.0000000000003
 2569.9999999999995
 5700.0
 6999.999999999998
```

You can also manually implement it using `dot` from the `LinearAlgebra` module like this:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> x = [10, 100, 1000, 10000]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
    10
   100
  1000
 10000

julia> y = [0;0;x;0;0]
8-element Array{Int64,1}:
     0
     0
    10
   100
  1000
 10000
     0
     0

julia> [dot(@view(y[i:i+2]), c) for i in 1:length(x)+2]
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
    2.0
   25.0
  257.0
 2570.0
 5700.0
 7000.0
```

Comment: Looks like the DPS.jl function can be `xcorr(x,c; padmode=:longest)`, without needing reverse.

Comment: indeed, but it seems that `padmode=:none` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that uses [ShiftedArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/ShiftedArrays.jl).

```
using ShiftedArrays

c = [0.7, 0.5, 0.2]
```

Create lagged versions of `x`, with initial zeros:

```
x = 1:5
xminus1 = lag(x, 1, default=0)
xminus2 = lag(x, 2, default=0)
```

Horizontally concatenate the vectors and use matrix multiplication with `c`:

```
X = [xminus2 xminus1 x]
X * c
```

Here's what `X` and `X * c` look like at the REPL:

```js
julia> X = [xminus2 xminus1 x]
5×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  1
 0  1  2
 1  2  3
 2  3  4
 3  4  5

julia> X * c
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.2
 0.9
 2.3
 3.7
 5.1
```

Note that this produces an output vector of length `length(x)`, not `length(x) + 2`. I'm not sure how it would make sense for the output to be of length `length(x) + 2`, as you requested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have a package for doing such things. The simplest use is like this:

```
julia> c = [0.7, 0.5, 0.2]; # from question

julia> x = [10, 100, 1000, 10_000]; # from another answer

julia> using Tullio, OffsetArrays

julia> @tullio y[i] := x[i]*c[3] + x[i-1]*c[2] + x[i-2]*c[1]
2-element OffsetArray(::Vector{Float64}, 3:4) with eltype Float64 with indices 3:4:
  257.0
 2570.0

julia> @tullio y[i] := x[i+k-3] * c[k] # sum over all k, range of i that's safe
2-element OffsetArray(::Array{Float64,1}, 3:4) with eltype Float64 with indices 3:4:
  257.0
 2570.0
```

Since `eachindex(c) == 1:3`, that's the range of `k`-values which this sums over, and the range of `i` is as big as it can be so that `i+k-3` stays inside `eachindex(x) == 1:4`.

To extend the range of `i` by padding `x` with two zeros in each direction, write `pad(i+k-3, 2)`. And to compute the shift of `i` needed to produce an ordinary 1-based Array, write `i+_` on the left (and then the `-3` makes no difference). Then:

```
julia> @tullio y[i+_] := x[pad(i+k, 2)] * c[k]
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
    2.0
   25.0
  257.0
 2570.0
 5700.0
 7000.0
```

On larger arrays, this won't be very fast (at the moment) as it must check at every step whether it is inside `x` or out in the padding. It's very likely that `DSP.conv` is a bit smarter about this. (Edit -- DSP.jl seems never to be faster for this `c`;  with a kernel of length 1000 it's faster with 10^6 elements in `x`.)